# Javascript username validation check in jqBootstrapValidation.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using jqBootstrapValidation.js ( http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/ )
and I want to check if a username that I choose is already existing.

I loaded all Usernames in an array:

```
$array = array("User1","User2",...);
```

and now I want to check if the username already exists while typing it in an input field and want to add the alert in the jqBootstrapValidation help-blocks.

Comment: try to use callback functionality  data-validation-callback-callback

Comment: Thank you for your answer - i don't know how i should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this if your user array is javascript array

javascript code

```
     function checkuser_callback_function($el, value, callback) {
        var $array = new Array("User1","User2");
        var valid = false;
        if($array.indexOf(value) == -1){
            valid = true;
        }
        callback({
            value: value,
            valid: valid,
            message: "User present."
        });
    }
```

HTML code

```
     <input type="text" data-validation-callback-callback="checkuser_callback_function" />
```

Comment: Thank you! But i have a php array.

Comment: than echo your php array as javascript array